# Merge by multiple criteria and split out duplicates into separate columns?

Tags: r, excel, vba, ms-access, spss

I'm quite sure this has been asked and answered at some point but I'm a novice and really lack the vocabulary to effectively find the question and solution. I have a simple task that I can't perform in Excel because of the internal memory limitations, but I don't know enough about SQL or R to figure out how to do it in either of those platforms.

I have two tables, one has unique entries with unique ID numbers, the other has multiple duplicates of those ID numbers, each showing a different number (representing each new salary over the course  of a career). I'm trying to map each of the salaries to the original unique ID table, creating new columns for every possible change (Salary1:Salary50). Ultimately I'll also need to map on the dates and differences of each change for analysis. Here's an example:

This is the unique ID table:

```
Table 1                 
ID  Salary1 Salary2 Salary3 Salary4 Salary5
1   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
2   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
3   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
4   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
5   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
```

Here's the salary table with duplicate IDs and the info I want:

```
Table2      
ID  Salary  SalaryDate
1   10  1/1/2014
1   11  1/1/2015
1   12  1/1/2016
2   12  1/1/2015
2   13  1/1/2016
3   10  1/1/2016
4   10  1/1/2014
4   12  1/1/2015
4   14  1/1/2016
5   10  1/1/2016
```

And the end state should look like this:

```
Table3                  
ID  Salary1 Salary2 Salary3 Salary4 Salary5
1   10  11  12  0   0
2   12  13  0   0   0
3   10  0   0   0   0
4   10  12  0   0   0
5   10  0   0   0   0
```

I built a multiple-criteria Vlookup to pull everything into the right columns but the dataset has well over 100,000 rows to check so it can't complete it memory-wise. Can anyone advise on how I can do the same thing in Access, R, SPSS or if there is some efficient Excel-VBA code I can use?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what a "Vlookup" is, but apparently you are looking for something like this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "ID  Salary  SalaryDate
                 1   10  1/1/2014
                 1   11  1/1/2015
                 1   12  1/1/2016
                 2   12  1/1/2015
                 2   13  1/1/2016
                 3   10  1/1/2016
                 4   10  1/1/2014
                 4   12  1/1/2015
                 4   14  1/1/2016
                 5   10  1/1/2016", header = TRUE)

#years of employment assuming the table is sorted by dates
DF$y <- ave(DF$ID, DF$ID, FUN = seq_along)

#reshape
library(reshape2)
dcast(DF, ID ~ y, value.var = "Salary", fill = 0)
#  ID  1  2  3
#1  1 10 11 12
#2  2 12 13  0
#3  3 10  0  0
#4  4 10 12 14
#5  5 10  0  0
```

Note that this is not a very useful data format in R. Your original data format seems much more useful for further analyses.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the IDs in Table1 are a subset of the IDs in Table2 and we want just those.   Also we want the first Salary for any ID in the `Salary1` result column, the second salary in the `Salary2` result column and so on.  First compute Seq which is 1 for the first date in any `ID`, 2 for the second and so on.  Then create a factor out of those sequence numbers whose levels are labelled by the Salary columns in Table1.  In the last statement subset `Table2` to the `ID` values of `Table1` (in the case of the data shown they are the same so it does not have any effect) and reshape from long to wide form using `xtabs`. No packages are used.

```
 Seq <- ave(1:nrow(Table2), Table2$ID, FUN = seq_along)
 Table0 <- Table1[-1] # Table0 is Table1 without ID column
 Table2$SalaryNo <- factor(Seq, levels = 1:ncol(Table0), labels = colnames(Table0))
 xtabs(Salary ~ ID + SalaryNo, data = subset(Table2, ID %in% Table1$ID))
```

giving:

```
   Salary_No
ID  Salary1 Salary2 Salary3 Salary4 Salary5
  1      10      11      12       0       0
  2      12      13       0       0       0
  3      10       0       0       0       0
  4      10      12      14       0       0
  5      10       0       0       0       0
```

**Note:** The tables were not provided in reproducible form and the solution may depend on specifically what they are so we have assumed this:

```
Lines1 <- "
ID  Salary1 Salary2 Salary3 Salary4 Salary5
1   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
2   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
3   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
4   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
5   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?"
Table1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "
ID  Salary  SalaryDate
1   10  1/1/2014
1   11  1/1/2015
1   12  1/1/2016
2   12  1/1/2015
2   13  1/1/2016
3   10  1/1/2016
4   10  1/1/2014
4   12  1/1/2015
4   14  1/1/2016
5   10  1/1/2016"
Table2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```

**Update:** Changed assumptions and code correspondingly. Also fixed an error (that did not affect the data shown but could affect other data).

Comment: I think this almost worked but I got an error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = Salary ~ Global.ID + SalaryNo,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'SalaryNo')

Comment: Have fixed.  (The bug did not affect the answer if the data in the Note was used.)